# Angular route resolver rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

My requirement is to have a user switch accounts when they click on a specific link. To fully switch accounts, I need to call two cold http observables and then load the data. The order does matter for all three requests.

1. First switchAccount$
2. Second updateSession$

Then I just need to get the pageData$ cold observable. I am currently using a resolver, but having difficulties structuring this with rxjs. I only care about the final page data in my component but I just need to make sure the user switches accounts and the session is updated or the backend api call will fail to get the page data.

I have tried to do the following but it is not working:

```
resolve(route): Observable<any> {
    const switchAccount$ = this.userService.switch('account2').pipe(last());
    const updateSession$ = this.userService.updateSesh();
    const pageData$ = this.pageService.getData();
    const switchAndUpdate$ = updateSession$.pipe(skipUntil(switchAccount$));


    return pageData$.pipe(skipUntil(switchAndUpdate$.pipe(last()); // problem is that switch account and page data get cancelled somehow??

}
```

Comment: what's switchDealer$? It's never declared.

Comment: should be switchAccount$ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine observable:

```
resolve(route): Observable<any> {
    const switchAccount$ = this.userService.switch('account2'); // I think last is not helpful
    const updateSession$ = this.userService.updateSesh();
    const pageData$ = this.pageService.getData();

    return switchAccount$.pipe(
         switchMap(() => updateSession$), // Or I think with margeMap works too
         switchMap(() => pageData$),
         catchError(error => of(error))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use switchMap for this:

```
return obs1$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => obs2$),
    switchMap(() => obs3$),
)
```